# Why I can't run VueJS with Express backend with hot reload?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, proxy, backend

I'm trying to use Express as a backend running a VueJS web application with hot reload, but I can't `FETCH` the content from the server.

vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: 'http://localhost:3000'
    }
}
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000

app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
    res.send({ "message": "Hello World" }) //Content
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`WebServer listening at port`);
});
```

That is running and `/hello` is working at port 3000.

Now, I'm starting both this way:

```
npm run server & nodemon server.js
```

Trying to fetch `/hello` in the Vue application, but it's not working. Am I missing anything?

```html
<template>
    <div class="flex-col">{{tasks}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name:"ListToDo",
    data(){
        return{
            tasks: []
        }
    },
    methods:{
      FETCH: function(){
        fetch("/tasks/")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.tasks=data)
      }
    },
    mount(){
      this.FETCH()      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The front-end is fetching `/tasks`, but the server does not have a route for `/tasks`, so it will respond with `404 Not Found`.

One solution is to add a route for `/tasks` to your server's Express instance:

```js
app.get('/tasks:myOptions(/*)?', (req, res) => {
    res.send({ message: 'tasks', myOptions: req.params.myOptions })
})
```

Or you can update your component to use the `/hello` route already setup in the server:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    FETCH: function() {
      fetch("/hello") 
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.tasks=data)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you prefer to keep your original `/hello` route while using `/tasks` from the client, the path will need to be rewritten client-side through the proxy, using the `pathRewrite` config shown below. However, this can't be done with the simple string proxy config, and specific route contexts (i.e., `/tasks`) must be specified:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/tasks': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000',
        pathRewrite: { '^/tasks' : '/hello' }
      }
    }
  }
}
```